# Accessing a Class Function when the Class instance is within a Struct

Tags: c++, class, struct

I have an array of structs -

```
struct MagicalUnicornBullets {
    PS2Sprite SparklyUnicornBullet();
    bool onscreen; 
};

MagicalUnicornBullets MagicalUnicornBullets[25];
```

I want to loop through the array, and initialise the contents of the struct.

Obviously, this is just the case of a for loop, and for the bool it's simply onscreen = false; but how would I initialise the SparklyUnicornBullet?

Right now my code is -

```
MagicalUnicornBullets[i].SparklyUnicornBullet.ScaleAbsolute(4,4);
```

I'm well aware this is wrong - but how do I access the class functions when they're within the Struct?

Comment: `SparklyUnicornBullet` is not an object, its a function prototype which is returning `PS2Sprite`. Is this what you are asking?. You need to do `PS2Sprite SparklyUnicornBullet;` (no `()`) to create an object. Then you can use the `ScaleAbsolute` method.

Comment: Okay... How do I initialise it in this case? Confused!

Comment: Isn't SparklyUnicornBullet the name of the PS2Sprite instance, and just constructing itself normally?

Comment: Thanks!! :) Compiling correctly! :D

Answer (score 0):

Realize that `SparklyUnicornBullet` is actually a member function which returns a `PS2Sprite` object.  This returned `PS2Sprite` has a member function `ScaleAbsolute` which you want to call.  So your code above is nearly correct.  You are simply missing `()`'s:

```
MagicalUnicornBullets[i].SparklyUnicornBullet().ScaleAbsolute(4,4);
```

That said, there's a number of things that's bad with your code.  For one, you are declaring an array that has the same name as an object:

```
MagicalUnicornBullets MagicalUnicornBullets[25];
```

I think this is allowed, but it is so evil and malmotivated that I can't even say that for certian, because I would reject any such code regardless of it's motivation or legality.  You should give the array a different name:

```
MagicalUnicornBullets bullets[25];
```

Next, your initialization loop is unneeded.  The code:

```
MagicalUnicornBullets MagicalUnicornBullets[25];
```

creates a C-style array of 25 `MagicalUnicornBullets` by calling each one's default constructor.  So the easiest thing to do is to simply provide a default constructor that does what you want:

```
struct MagicalUnicornBullets {
  MagicalUnicornBullets();
  // ...
};

MagicalUnicornBullets::MagicalUnicornBullets()
:  onscreen(false)
{
  SparklyUnicornBullet().ScaleAbsolute(4,4)
}
```

Now there's no need for a loop at all.  All 25 will be constructed and initialized the way you want.

Finally, usually in C++ it's advantagerous to not use a C-style array at all, but a collection class such as `std::vector`.